# Curl of Normal Vector Field Is Zero on Surface

Tags: vector-analysis, curl

Let $S$ be a smooth surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $\vec{N}$ be a unit normal vector field along $S$.

1. Is it true that $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{N} = 0$ on $S$ for any smooth extension of $\vec{N}$?
2. Is it true that $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F} = 0$ on $S$ for any vector field $\vec{F}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\vec{F} = 0$ on $S$?

Thank you.

Comment: As a hint to get started: A typical surface $S$ is the set of points $x,y,z$ at which a smooth function $f$ is zero. The normal vector field on this surface is $\nabla f\,.$  The curl of this gradient is ... ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP does not respond.

Comment: I think the normal vector field is parallel to $\nabla f$, not equal to it.

Comment: Actually, I asked this question because I do not know how to delete the term $\nabla (1/|\nabla f|) \times \nabla f$.

Comment: WLOG you can choose $f$ that describes the surface $S=\{f=0\}$ such that $\|\nabla f\|\equiv 1\,.$

Comment: How can I prove it? My question (1) is exactly its proof.